# Osgi synchronization services

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, synchronize

It is posible to syncronize an osgi service from outside it,from an other bundle ?

```
OsgiService oS = retrieveService(BundleContext);

synchronized(oS){
...
}
```

I dont want to alow the calls from outside a bundle to do changes during a specific method execution inside.

The bundle is registered and active. I am working under Equinox framework.

Comment: If you want to use an OSGi service from another system you should think about using DOSGi, CXF does have a pretty good implementation that also gives you the ability to share a OSGi service as a web-service.

Comment: Since the proposed code is a bad idea in general I am very curious to what your real world use case is?

Comment: synchronizing a self made version controller with real time events that could induce version value to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When you publish a service you declare it as being generally available, without constraints on the way in which it is used. For example you cannot limit other bundles to call methods in a particular order, or require them to use synchronization, or to always call from a particular thread. Therefore you must assume that you *will* be called from any thread, without synchronization, etc.

If the internal state of your service implementation is fragile and requires synchronization, then it is your responsibility to do it inside your implementation. You cannot force this work onto somebody else.

Comment: I have to use them from outside,so i think i would have to implement a Semaphore solution.

Comment: From outside what? Outside the bundle? Outside the JVM? The computer?

Comment: Outside the bundle,same computer same jvm

Comment: Okay. Well that's the bog-standard usage of OSGi Services. That is, if you're not at least publishing outside the bundle, then you don't need a service.

Answer (score 1):

Under specific constraints, yes, as the Equinox framework does not create proxies for services. However, that is a very brittle solution, as other parts of the system may or may not synchronize these calls...

Did you know you can replace services in OSGi? Create a class that supports all the proper interfaces for your  use case, but which is published as a service with a higher [SERVICE_RANKING](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#SERVICE%5FRANKING) property than the existing service; this will cause this instance to be preferred when looking up services. Now, this class delegates all the method calls to the original service, which it obtains either using Declarative Services, a ServiceTracker or the BundleContext; in all cases using a Filter for SERVICE_RANKING. This allows you to intercept all method calls and f.e. log or synchronize them.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Service ranking isn't a reliable way to intercept services, because the service consumers are not forced to pay any attention to the ranking. If you really need to design some kind of "aspect" service like this then you should use Filter/ListenerHooks to completely hide the wrapped service. But I think this is probably way overkill for what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Indeed. Note that I was under the impression that per the OSGi spec, when a single service is requested, the framework returns the service(reference) with the highest ranking (5.2.6, 5.2.8, 701.7.5.11).

Comment: Yes that's true. So long as no other filter applies, etc.

Comment: And as long as you're in time ... the approach creates ordering problems since the non-synced service might be registered first.

Comment: So does using Hooks, as they need to be registered first.